# Fill area between two dates in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to create a chart to compare the overlap of dates. Sort of a timeline with a bar chart that starts on the Onset Date and ends at the Offset date for each category.

I have included sample data below. For this data, I would have 5 bar charts going horizontal with dates on the X-axis. The Y-axis can be the Category type.

Been playing around with line and bar charts in excel but they just are not right. Any suggestions would be great!

```
Category    Onset     Offset
B1        12/1/2014   3/1/2015
B2        10/1/2014   1/1/2015
B3        5/1/2014    1/1/2015
B4        6/1/2014    8/1/2014
B5        6/1/2014    10/1/2014
```

Answer (score 2):

I presume that you want something like this:

[image]

Set up another region in your workbook
that is the same dimensions as your data area (3×6, in your example). 
It can be on another sheet; for now, let’s say it is in columns `X`-`Z`. 
Assuming that the data you’ve shown us are `A1:C6`, it will be `X1:Z6`. 
Set

- `X1` → `=A1`. 
  Drag one column to the right to get `Y1` → `=B1`;
  drag down to cover all the data (i.e., row 6). 
  The “Onset” dates should now be displayed as numbers
  (e.g., 41974, 41913, 41760, 41791, and 41791).
  Note that you can do the same thing as the above with “Copy” and “Paste Link”.
- `Z2` → `=C2-B2` and drag down. 
  This, obviously, gives the duration of each `Bn` category.

Then

- Create a “Stacked Bar” chart of the `X1:Z6` data.
- Select the “Onset” data series and format it as “No fill” and “No line”. 
  (I had to click on “No line” twice to get it to believe me.)
- Select the “Horizontal Axis” (i.e., the X axis)
  and set the “Number” format to “Date”.
- Optionally,
  go into “Axis Options” and adjust the minimum and/or maximum value. 
  For example, for your data,
  Excel defaulted the X axis to a range of 41600-42100,
  even though the lowest value in your data is 41760. 
  I produced the chart shown above by changing the minimum value to 41700. 
  Make note of the Major Units value. 
  For me, it initially defaulted to 100,
  but changed to 50 when I changed the minimum value. 
  100 is a better value. 
  Adjust to whatever works for your data.
- Optionally, delete the “Legend”.

Another option:

- Somewhere in your workbook, compute `MIN(B2:C6)` and `MAX(B2:C6)`. 
  Format them to display as numbers. 
  Use these as the minimum and maximum value for the X axis. 
  (You’ll have to copy them as literal numeric values,
  and they won’t automatically update if the data change.)
- If you want your X axis to represent whole months,
  use `EOMONTH(MIN(B2:C6), -1) + 1` and `EOMONTH(MAX(B2:C6), 0)`
  to get the first day of the first month in your data set,
  and the last day of the last month.