# Excel stacked bar chart not starting at zero

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to create a stacked-bar chart in Excel 2013 that will appear as a Gantt chart, with multiple events on each row, much like the picture below.

[image: staff rota example]

However my problem is that in order to plot a shift that doesn't start at 0, I need to input a value (in this case, 5) above the source data to move the values along to where I want them.

Changing the axes is not an option as they need to show 24 hours.

Here is my source data:

[image: data]

I have left a grey border around the first stack for clarity, but is there a way to present the same data points `[1, 0.25, 2.25, 0.5, 1, 0.25, 2.75]` without putting a 5 before them?

Or is there a much better way to arrive at the same thing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fill area between two dates in excel](https://superuser.com/questions/1022226/fill-area-between-two-dates-in-excel)

Comment: Could you talk me through an easier to understand answer than that? I am not getting very far at the moment, I can't replicate the picture in that link.

Comment: OK, I’d like to help you, but I’m going to need a bit of help understanding your question. I could almost read it as follows: “I have the numbers 1, 0.25, 2.25, 0.5, 1, 0.25, 2.75, and I need to chart them as 5, 6, 6.25, 8.5, 9, 10, 10.25, 13 without telling Excel to start at 5.” Now I’m sure that’s not what you’re asking, but, as I said, I don’t understand what you are asking. You seem to be saying that you have the 1, 0.25, 2.25, 0.5, 1, 0.25, 2.75 numbers in Column `G`.  What do you need to do that you’re having trouble with?